# Splatting pip requirements using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, pip, scripting

I've trying to install my python's project requirements using powershell splatting.

To get the requirements files, I use this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "requirements*"
```

Then I want to install packages, but I dont know how to splat the file list so that something like this:

```
pip install -r requirements1.txt -r requirements2.txt ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) to construct pairs of `-r`-file-name arguments, relying on the fact that when you pass a *collection* of arguments to a call to an external program, PowerShell passes the elements of that collection as individual arguments:

```bash
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "requirements*"

pip install $files.ForEach({ '-r', $_.Name })
```

Comment: @Joaquín, yes, it does what you want and only calls `pip install` only _once_. You can check what is being passed with `cmd /c echo pip install $files.ForEach({ '-r', $_.Name })`